# PhantomJs timeout

Tags: timeout, jasmine, phantomjs

I am using Jasmine with PhantomJS to run test cases.

In my typical test case, I make a service call, wait for response and confirm response.

Some requests can return in a few seconds and some can take up to a minute to return.

When ran through PhantomJS, the test case fails for the service call that is supposed to take a minute ( fails because the response is not yet received).

What's interesting is that the test passes when ran through Firefox.

I have tried looking at tcpdump and the headers are same for requests through both browsers, so this looks like a browser timeout issue.

Has anyone had a similar issue ? Any ideas as to where could the timeout be configured ? Or do you think the problem is something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Ah the pain of PhantomJS.

Apparently it turned out that I was using javascript's `bind` function which is not supported in PhantomJS . 
This was causing the test to fail which resulted in messing up state of some global variable( my fault) and hence the failure.

But the root cause was using `bind`.

Solution: try getting a shim for `bind` like this from  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue. All you have to do is add setTimeout to exit

```js
 setTimeout(function() {phantom.exit();},20000); // stop after 20 sec ( add this before you request your webpage )

 page.open('your url here', function (status) {
  // operations here
 });
```